# Custom CSS File wont work on second Page

Tags: customization, menus, themes, css

i created a custom Theme in WordPress and everything is working fine and the CSS is loading to my index.php. So now i copy-pasted the index.php and renamed it, then i went to the indexCopy site and the CSS wont load. In the Code, everything is the sam, except the fileName. When i go back to my index.php, the css IS working. Do you need Code examples for this issue?

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Is this a WordPress site? I don’t understand what “went to the indexCopy site” means? How are you doing that?

Comment: I am pressing a button on my "Main WordPress Page" then i got redirected to my copied index.php file and then, the css wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your are not creating a proper WordPress template when you copy your index.php.

Here you can find the list of standard template files: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#id=%22Template_Files_List%22

And here you can learn how to create a custom template:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

My guess is you need to add the following to the top of your index copy. Then make sure to select this template from the edit post/page view to use it on the front end (it should use the css).

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Index Copy
*/
```

Comment: yeah, a part of it is working now. The theme is loading correctly but the CSS doesnt load :/ i read the 2 links you gave me and now I understand a bit more about wordpress but the thing with the not loading CSS File, is still a secret 4 me.

Comment: OK, good that is progress!  Without knowing more its hard to troubleshoot the exact issue.  So I would start with how WP loads scripts and styles you can learn more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/.  There might be something there that will help highlight what needs to be updated in your template to get the styles working.

Comment: I moved the CSS Import Code to my new .php File and now its working. I'll try it later with the functions.php. Thank you <3